# parameterizing a dynamic drop down list in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to get it so that I can assign a variable to the value that the user selects in my drop-down menu of countries. I have done this before with tables, but not drop down lists, so I'm not sure how. Ultimately, I am trying to have a new page return a table for the country selected once the user clicks the submit button, and know I need a varaiable assigned to what the user selects. Here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test2</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body> 
<?php include("header.php"); ?> 
    <article>   
    <!-- This describes the choice of country name selection -->
        <h1>Please select your country:</h1>

        <form action='processformD.php' method='GET'>
            <select name='CountryName'>

<?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM alphabetizedCountryNames;";
                $result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
                // $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                ?>
                <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    extract($row);
                    echo "<option value='$CountryName'>$CountryName\n";
                }
                ?>
            </select>


<div class="centerthatshit"><?php echo "<p><input type='submit' value='submit' /></p>\n"; ?></div>
        </form>

</article>   
<?php include("footer.php"); ?> 

</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At first glance, your <option> tag is not closed. Not sure if there are other issues as well.

Comment: you mean like right here?echo "<option value='$CountryName'>$CountryName\n"

Comment: Yes. [Here is an example of what it should end up like.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples)

Comment: `"<option value='$CountryName'>$CountryName</option>\n"` should work better

Comment: Ok thanks, I did that and was still having problems. Think it is something wrong with the php file that I am linking to, upon the click of the "submit" button, since everything else seems right

Comment: Are you getting the country name from `$_GET['CountryName']`?